# SQL Server 2017 Express silent installation

Tags: installation, command-line-arguments, sql-server-2017-express

With our Installer, Customer wants us to check if the SQL server is installed or not and it is not installed, the installer should install it. Also,  the installation should be silent and not ask anything to the user as they are not techies. Now by sending the full SQL server 2017 express installer along our application could be one option but that will make the installer size very big. To avoid that, I thought of the online installer. But the online installer seems not to be taking arguments and throwing exception. Customer and Project team don't want user's involvement. Could any of you guys suggest any other option where I can sent the small Online installer and launch it with some command line options / configuration to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what tool do you use to create your setup packages, but the Advanced Installer packaging tool addresses your requirement. You can have a look on [Install SQL Server 2017 Silently/with BasicUI](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=36298) tutorial on their online docs. Hope this helps somehow.

Disclaimer: I use Advanced Installer tool to package my .Net application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will check this first thing Monday.

Comment: Was just going to suggest the same.